# Eclipse Egit - Finish feature does not delete feature

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit, git-flow

I am trying to create a new feature branch using Eclipse Egit Git flow and then merge this with develop branch after things are done.

**Issue: The feature branch does not get deleted after finish work flow is done.**

**Using GIT Bash** - when I create a new feature and finish and commit it. Everything works as expected. Codes are merged with develop branch and then the feature branch is deleted.

**Using Eclipse** - I create a new feature, finish it and commit. The feature branch is getting committed to the git lab server.(No issues here) I also tried to merge the feature branch to develop and commit. The changes are committed to the server - No issues there. But the feature branch still exists on my local. According to normal git flow (bash flow), the feature branch is deleted when it is finished.

Is this a abnormal behavior with Eclipse git flow? I tried to uncheck this box, that should delete my feature branch. but it didn't happen.

[image]

Comment: Implementation of the option _Keep branch_: see [Eclipse bug 477786](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=477786)

Comment: that option is available. but doesn't seem to work. Check the image above.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a bug. Please report it to Eclipse as a new bug with a link to the mentioned bug. Do you know since which JGit/EGit version this bug exists (it looks like you are using JGit/EGit 4.9 or 4.10)?